# Proving Two Statements of the Implicit Function Theorem are the Same.

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

In *Mathematical Analysis* by Andrew Browder, he states the implicit function theorem as follows:

> Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, and let
> $\textbf{f}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a mapping of class
> $C^r, r \geq 1$. Let $\mathbf{p}=(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$, and let
> $\Sigma$ be the "level surface" of $\mathbf{f}$ through $\mathbf{p}$:
>
> $$\Sigma=\{\mathbf{q}\in \Omega:
> \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{q})=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{p})\}.$$ Define $S \in\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ by
> $S(\mathbf{h})=\mathrm{d}\mathbf{f}_\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{h},\mathbf{0})$
> and $T \in \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ by
> $T(\mathbf{k})=\mathrm{d}\mathbf{f}_\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{k}).$
> Suppose that $T$ iis invertible. Then there exists a neighborhood $U$
> of $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ a neighborhood $W$ of
> $\mathbf{a}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and a mapping $\mathbf{g}: W
> \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which is of class $C^r$, such that
>
> $$\Sigma \cap U=\{(\mathbf{s},\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{s}): \mathbf{s} \in W
> \}.$$ Furthermore $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{g}_{\mathbf{a}} = -T^{-1}S$.

This I thought was a rather convoluted statement, so I looked the statement up on Wikipedia, which states:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuously
> differentiable function, and let $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ have coordinates
> $(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})$. Fix a point $(\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}) =
> (a_1,\dots,a_n, b_1,\dots, b_m)$ with $f(\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}) =
> > \mathbf{0}$, where $\mathbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the zero vector.
> If the Jacobian matrix (this is the right-hand panel of the Jacobian
> matrix shown in the previous section): $$J_{f, \mathbf{y}} (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) = \left [ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}
> (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \right ]$$ is invertible, then there exists
> an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ containing $\textbf{a}$ such that
> there exists a unique continuously differentiable function $g: U \to
> \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $ g(\mathbf{a}) = \mathbf{b}$, and $
> f(\mathbf{x}, g(\mathbf{x})) = \mathbf{0} ~ \text{for all} ~
> \mathbf{x}\in U$. Moreover, denoting the left-hand panel of the
> Jacobian matrix shown in the previous section as: $$ J_{f, \mathbf{x}}
> (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) = \left [ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}
> (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \right ], $$ the Jacobian matrix of partial
> derivatives of $g$ in $U$ is given by the matrix product: $$
> \left[\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} (\mathbf{x})\right]_{m\times
> n} =- \left [ J_{f, \mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}, g(\mathbf{x})) \right ]_{m
> \times m} ^{-1} \, \left [ J_{f, \mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x}, g(\mathbf{x})) \right ]_{m \times n} $$

My question is: how are they the same statement? I'm mostly confused how to prove that the $\Sigma \cap U$ condition in the Browder definition is equivalent to the "$ g(\mathbf{a}) = \mathbf{b}$, and $
f(\mathbf{x}, g(\mathbf{x})) = \mathbf{0} ~ \text{for all} ~
\mathbf{x}\in U$" (or really $W$) condition on Wikipedia.

Comment: $(s, g(s))\in \Sigma\Rightarrow f(\vec{s}, \ g(\vec{s}))=f(\vec{p})$ (Look back how $\Sigma$ is defined.) And the wiki’s definition said $f(\vec{x}, \ g(\vec{x}))=0$, i.e.  $f(\vec{x}, \ g(\vec{x})) =f(\vec{a}, \vec{b})$, since it said $f(\vec{a}, \vec{b}) =0$. (If you want to apply the wiki edition of the theorem but $f(\vec{a}, \vec{b}) \neq 0$, then your can subtract $f$ by a constant, since we do not care the “absolute value” of $f$.)